# Windows XP Task Bar stuck on right side of screen

Tags: windows-xp, taskbar

Due to a misclick/drag, the task bar is on the right side of the screen in Windows XP.

The task bar is not locked, but it will not respond to any drag movement, and is stuck!

Any suggestions or experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

As @EKW mentioned, there my be an empty toolbar obstructing the blank space where you can usually click and drag the taskbar from. A quick way around this is to click and drag from the clock.

Comment: I disabled the quick launch toolbar and then moved the taskbar back.  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/253679

I can't really add anything more to this KB article, though if it seems like you can't move the taskbar, there's usually something 'covering' it, like a toolbar (which you can disable through the right-click menu).