# How do I move the task bar?

Tags: windows-xp, taskbar

My mother was moving some things around on her desktop the other day and somehow moved her task bar. It went from horizontal along the bottom of the screen to vertical along the left edge of the screen.
Usually it is my job to be the tech support at my house; but I'm stumped!
How do I move the task at back the way it was?
Oh and it's Windows XP:)

Comment: It should just be a case of right-clicking a blank area on the taskbar, making sure **Lock the Taskbar** is not ticked, then dragging it to the bottom of the screen. Does that not work?

Comment: @James I'll have to check; I can't right now because I'm not using that computer I'll let you know if that works:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just drag it to any side of the screen. (if it's locked it wouldn't have moved.)

Comment: My problem is that although I can move it left and right; I can't go up and down which is what I need!

Comment: right click on the taskbar (make sure your not clicking on a icon) press properties > taskbar location on screen > bottom.

Comment: do you mean thinner or thicker or you can move all the way across the screen?

Comment: exactly what I mean! Thicker, thinner and I think all the way across the screen but I can't remember.

Comment: you need to hold down the middle of the taskbar (not the edges) and drag it the bottom.

Comment: Moving the taskbar in XP is a bit harder than in windows 7, as you have to move the mouse to the bottom center before it will show as moved. They built this in to prevent accidental moving of the window. The concequence is that if you still move it, its even harder to get it back.

Answer (score 1):

I found this in the related section to the right.
[Windows XP Task Bar stuck on right side of screen](https://superuser.com/questions/398303/windows-xp-task-bar-stuck-on-right-side-of-screen?rq=1)

The gist: A Microsoft support article states that you can set the task bar back to default by booting into safe mode. And the problem might be an empty toolbar using the space.